# Why i have error, when trying to render site with eleventy?

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

I'm trying to add a header as a component to eleventy, the console gives an error that there is no such template: "Error: template not found: header"
Tried names for the header: header, 'header', header.njk, 'header.njk'
Where am I wrong?

Screens:

[image: file eleventy.js]

[image: files location in project]

[image: trying to call my template]

[image: console error]

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue. Is your code in a repo somewhere we can see?

Answer (score 1):

[Nunjucks `{% include %}`](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#include) needs the file extension to properly include the file. While you said you also tried `{% include 'header.njk' %}`, I wasn't able to reproduce the issue if the file extension (.njk) was provided.

I've created a [minimal setup in Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lacy-garrulous-banon?path=src%2F_layouts%2Fsingle.njk%3A7%3A0) to replicate your issue, but it seems to work for me. Take a look and see if anything is different in your project.